# How to get all the servers and channels the bot is in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I want to know how to access all servers and channels the bot is in for a `/info` page.

The following is an example:

[image: Example of info command]

What I've tried:

- Something somebody gave me on a coding discord server that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
@commands.slash_command(name="botinfo", description="Get bot info!")
async def botinfo(self, ctx):
    amount = 0
    bot_channels = 0
    members = 0
    for i in self.bot.guilds:
        amount += 1
        bot_channels += len(i.channels)
        members += i.member_count
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Bot Info",
        description=f"I'm in {amount} servers! \n I'm in {bot_channels} channels! \n There are {members} members that can use my commands!",
        color=discord.Color.random()
    )
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

### How this works:

`bot` is the bot instanced at the beginning of most pycord files with `bot = discord.Bot()`

To get the amount of guilds:

1. `bot` has the built-in attribute `guilds` that [has a list of guilds](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/clients.html#discord.Bot.guilds).
2. By looping through the list (or using `len(bot.guilds)` both work)

To get all channels:

1. You can use `i.channels` (`i` is the iterator for iterating over the guilds). ([Docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Guild.channels))
2. Use `len()` to get the length of that attribute.

To get the member count:

DANGER DO NOT ITERATE OVER ALL `guild.members` (It's just slow)

1. Just use `guild.member_count`. ([Docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Guild.member_count))

Answer (score 2):

bot.guilds gives you a list of guilds your bot is it, but it might take some time for it to load the list of guilds, so what I did was that at first it takes  the guild ID's from a text file and after some time it uses bot.guilds and writes over the text file with an updated guild info.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
from discord import *


bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot("$", intents=intents)

with open("./guild_ids.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as data:
    guilds = list(map(lambda x: Object(int(x)), data.read().split("\n")))

guild_ids = list(map(lambda x: str(x.id), bot.guilds))

with open("./guild_ids.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(guild_ids))
```

Hope that helps.